# An entire function $f$ that maps horizontal lines to horizontal lines

Tags: complex-analysis

An entire function $f$ that maps horizontal lines to horizontal lines why do have a derivative $f'$ that is  real and $\ne0$ at all points $z\in\Bbb C$?
I have some intution that horizontal line can be described from the action on imaginary axis. Then what cocclusion can be drawn from that? Can anyone explain me rigorously??
Thanks in advance

Comment: How can you characterise horizontal lines? If you restrict $h$ to be real in $$f'(z) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h},$$ what does that tell you about the derivative?

Comment: I think it would be real

Comment: Indeed. And how do you see that?

Comment: Because $f(z+h)-f(z)$ is real

Comment: Right. So that shows that $f'$ is real-valued [and hence constant].

Answer (score 0):

Consider a point $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\ne0$. The horizontal line $\ell$ through the point $z_0$ has the parametric representation
$$\ell:\quad t\mapsto z(t)=z_0+t\qquad(-\infty <t<\infty)\ ,$$
and the image of this line is given by
$$f(\ell):\quad t\mapsto w(t)=f(z_0+t)\qquad(-\infty <t<\infty)\ .$$

By assumption $f(\ell)$ is again a horizontal line; so the tangent vector ${\bf v}$ to $f(\ell)$ at $w_0=f(z_0)$ has to be horizontal. According to the chain rule one has $$w'(0)=f'(z_0)\cdot 1\ne0\ .$$ 
It follows that the direction of ${\bf v}$ is given by the direction of $w'(0)$, and this direction is horizontal iff $f'(z_0)$ is real.